# Arduino SDK: Error code 107 "invalid JSON" when saving object

Tags: c, parse-platform, arduino-yun

I'm getting started with the Arduino Yun Parse SDK and followed the basic example to save an object.

I'm reading a temperature from a sensor every minute and saving it to Parse as such:

```
void loop() {
  delay(60000);

  float temperature = dht.readTemperature();
  if (isnan(temperature)) return;

  ParseObjectCreate create;
  create.setClassName("SensorReading");
  create.add("temperature", temperature);
  ParseResponse response = create.send();

  Serial.print(response.getJSONBody());
  if (!response.getErrorCode()) {
     String objectId = response.getString("objectId");
     Serial.print("Object id:");
     Serial.println(objectId);
  } else {
     Serial.println("Failed to save the object");
  }
  response.close();
}
```

This will work initially, but if I keep it running for an extended period of time (30+ minutes), I start getting this error:

```
{"code":107,"error":"invalid JSON"}
```

It will give this error code for all subsequent saves until I restart my sketch.

I'm a bit confused as to how the JSON generated by the Parse API could become invalid after a while. The temperature value is a valid float even in those failed save requests.

Maybe it has to do with my Parse token expiring? Am I supposed to refresh it by calling Parse.begin() again?

Answer (score 0):

This was due to a memory leak in the Parse Arduino Yun library version 1.0.0. It's fixed in version 1.0.1.